# DELETE to /oauth/personal-access-tokens/token not supported

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

I am having some weird problem with laravel passport that doesnt happen on localhost but it does online on webhosting when I want to revoke token.

```
DELETE to /oauth/personal-access-tokens/26b3a9adf97f20949156798fc491687446cacde48914124c717b6f3318866afd9590e0ddabc5efc1 not supported.
```

Everything else works.

Comment: Do you have any reverse proxy/middleware/... like varnish or nginx?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what are you talking about :D

Comment: This webserver configuration may be causing this. What http server are you using? Do you have any other route that use HTTP DELETE?

Comment: Apache, I see that put, patch or delete doesn work...

Comment: I have no access to change apache settings, its shared hosting.. Is there some way or should I change from those to POST?

Comment: You may want to contact your webhost, or change for a different one that does support this.

Comment: have you tried method spoofing? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: could you give me example with passport that can do that ? :D i dont see one

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where is this `DELETE` being initiated from? I haven't used passport at all so I'm not able to provide anything without more context.

Comment: Inside vendor registered routes for passport with delete and put for controllers :D and I am using vue and axios :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a local passport environment, this seemed to work for me in **PersonalAccessTokens.vue**:

```
revoke(token) {
    axios.post('/oauth/personal-access-tokens/' + token.id, {'_method': 'DELETE'})
    .then(response => {
         this.getTokens();
    });
}
```

While axios will send a post, `{'_method': 'DELETE'}` tells **Laravel** to use the `delete` endpoint defined in `Laravel\Passport\RouteRegistrar`:

```
$router->delete('/tokens/{token_id}', [
    'uses' => 'AuthorizedAccessTokenController@destroy',
]);
```

Comment: it works on local everything, now i changed vendor routes register to post and vue axios to post and it works on webhosting as well

Comment: You shouldnt have to change any routes, just the above vue code

Comment: i did and i kept getting 405 error for unallowed methods

Comment: did you rebuild your vue components?

Comment: I received the 405s too, without `{'_method': 'DELETE'}`

Comment: oh didnt see that, ill try it later went out to clear head, anyway i trust you will accept answer